# Getting exact match for pattern in bash

Tags: regex, string, bash, matching

I am having trouble with bash matching exactly a pattern. Say for example I am only wanting to matching letters before my file extension like this "test.bam", but in the case a number is included like, "t1st.bam" I get this output: "st".

```
hello="t1est.bam"
re="([a-zA-Z]+)\.bam"


if [[ $hello =~ $re ]]; then

    result=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
    echo "unable to parse string"
fi
echo "$result"
```

What I would like it to do is not to match the pattern at all if a non-alpha character is provided and go into the 'else' block.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the match to start at the beginning of the string, add the `^` anchor:

```
re='^([a-zA_Z_]+)\.bam'
```

Comment: This works! Can I ask though what does it mean if you put it on the inside of the group like (^[.....})?

Comment: @ErikR: [A Brief Introduction to Regular Expressions](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html) covers this. A caret `^` indicates a match with the beginning of a line, and it can also negate a set of characters (e.g. `[^a-d]` means "not a, b, c, or d"). A caret in the middle of the expression will match with a newline, which is usually unintended.